# How to add OrbitControls on three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm a beginner of three.js and I would like to add OrbitControl. I'm trying to add these two lines for the camera and render the scene, but it doesn't work. Could you advise where I should put these codes and anything else I need to add to turn on OrbitControls?

1. controls =  new $.OrbitControls(camera);
2. controls.update();

Your help would be much appreciated.

```js
const $=THREE;
var renderer;
renderer = new $.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});


/* data */
var dataSet = [];
dataSet[0] =[ 0,1,0,-1,-2,0,1,0,-1,-2];
dataSet[1] =[ 0,-1,2,1,0,0,-1,0,1,0];
dataSet[2] =[ 0,-3,0,2,1,2,-1,0,1,2];
dataSet[3] =[ 0,1,0,-1,0,0,1,0,-1,0];
dataSet[4] =[ 0,-1,-2,0,-2,0,-1,-2,0,-2];
dataSet[5] =[ 0,1,2,1,2,0,1,2,1,2];
dataSet[6] =[ '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];

var perDay = 500;
var frameRate = 40;
var yPow = 12;
var r = 0;
var idx = 0;
var dataLength = dataSet[0].length;

var scene = new $.Scene();
var cm = new $.Object3D();
var sb = new $.Object3D();

const camera = new $.PerspectiveCamera(35, 700/500, 0.5, 10000);
camera.position.z = 200;
camera.position.x = 30;

// OrbitControls
// controls =  new $.OrbitControls(camera);

var grp = new $.Object3D();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
document.getElementById('data').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var teamColor=[ 0x3333ff,0xffff00, 0xff0000, 0x333333, 0x191970,0x000066  ];
var ballGeo = [];
var ballMat = [];
var balls = [];
var smallBallMat = [];
var pngs =[];


for( var i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ ){
    ballGeo.push( new $.SphereGeometry( 10,10,10 ) );
    ballMat.push( new $.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:teamColor[i],specular:0xffffff, shininess:40,ambient:0x333333,wireframe:false,overdraw:true,map:pngs[i] } ));
    balls.push( new $.Mesh( ballGeo[i],ballMat[i] ));
    balls[i].position.x = i*12;
    balls[i].rotation.y = -Math.PI/2;
    grp.add( balls[i] );

    smallBallMat.push( new $.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:teamColor[i],specular:teamColor[i],ambient:0x333333,shininess:50,wireframe:false,overdraw:true,opacity:0.8,transparent:true }));

}

var tmp;var pargeo=[];var xx=0,yy=0,zz=frameRate+10000;
var pmat=[],parSet=[];
var sbSet=[],sbm=[],vSet = [];

for( i = 0; i< 6 ; i++ ){
    sbSet[i] = new $.Geometry();
    for( var j=0;j<dataSet[i].length;j++ ){
            xx=i*12;
            yy=dataSet[i][j]*yPow;
            zz+=frameRate;
            tmp=new $.Mesh(new $.SphereGeometry(6,8,8));
            tmp.position.x=xx;
            tmp.position.y=yy;
            tmp.position.z=zz;
        $.GeometryUtils.merge(sbSet[i], tmp);
    }
            zz=frameRate+10000;
    sbm[i] = new $.Mesh(sbSet[i],smallBallMat[i]);
    sb.add( sbm[i]);
    vSet[i]=sbm[i].geometry.vertices.length/dataSet[i].length
}

scene.add( grp );
cm.add( camera );
scene.add( cm );
grp.add(sb);

var backPlGeo = new $.PlaneGeometry( 84,1200,0,100 );
var backPl = new $.Mesh( backPlGeo  , new $.MeshBasicMaterial( {wireframe:true,color:0xeeeeee}));
grp.add( backPl );
backPl.position.x=30;

var light = new $.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
light.position = new $.Vector3(-80, 20, 120);

scene.add( light );
var ambient = new $.AmbientLight(0xcccccc);
grp.add(ambient);

grp.rotation.x=Math.PI/24;
grp.rotation.y=Math.PI/12;

var steps=-5;
var reverse = false;
var stop = false ;
var max=4;
var curMax=4;
var tmp;
sb.position.z=-frameRate*2;

var render = function () {
    var diff;
    if( !stop ){
        if( r > frameRate*2 && idx < dataLength-1){
            for( var i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++ ){
                diff = dataSet[i][idx+1]-dataSet[i][idx];
                if(max < Math.abs(dataSet[i][idx+1]) )max=Math.abs(dataSet[i][idx+1]);
                balls[i].position.y+=(diff*yPow)/frameRate;
            }

            sb.position.z--;
            if( r%frameRate == 0 ){
                for( i = 0 ; i <=5 ; i++){
                    for( var vi=0;vi < vSet[i];vi++){
                        sbm[i].geometry.vertices[vi+vSet[i]*idx].z-=10000;
                    }
                    sbm[i].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
                }

            idx++;
                curMax=max;
            }
        }

    // controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    setTimeout( arguments.callee , perDay/frameRate);
        r++;

    }
 };

 render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r127/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three-orbitcontrols-ts@0.1.2/dist/index.js"></script>

<div id="data">
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using `three-orbitcontrols-ts`, which is TypeScript, not JavaScript, and it hasn't been updated since 2018. Have you looked at the source code on the [OrbitControls Example](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit)? Try using the official version instead: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. hmm,  I will check the official documents.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Marquizzo Thank you so much! you are right and I could solve the issue.